# Limit of an integral as $n\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, limits

I don't know how to solve this one, and I'm totally lost with it. $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0 ^1 \frac{x^n}{e-2x}dx=0$$

When I look at the upper part of the fraction, when $n$ is increasing, the lower part becomes negligible, and regarding the integral, when the power of $x^n$ is increasing, the slope is increasing as well, but the area between $0$ and $1$ is decreasing.

I'm lost on how to prove that the limit of this integral is $0$.

Comment: thank you so much, i've learned a lot from the answers and the different kind of approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
\left|\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,dx}{\mathrm{e}-2x}\right|\le 
\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,dx}{\mathrm{e}-2}=\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}-2}\int_0^1 x^n\,dx=
\frac{1}{\mathrm{e}-2}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The observation that $\left|\dfrac{x^{n}}{e-2x}\right|\leq\dfrac{1}{e-2x}$ and $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{1}{e-2x}dx<\infty$, and then Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: LDCT is overkill here I think

Answer (score 1):

$$I_{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n}{(e-2x)}dx=\frac{1}{e}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^n(e-2x+2x)}{(e-2x)}dx$$
$$I_n=\frac{1}{e}\int_{0}^{1}x^ndx+\frac{2}{e}I_{n+1}$$ now assuming limit exists as the first integral in the r.h.s goes to zero we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}I_n=\frac{2}{e}I_{n}$$
therefore $I_n=0$